# Cloudfront can't access S3 Bucket (different bucket from S3 static hosting one)

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, pre-signed-url

Currently I'm getting a signed url for a s3 bucket and performing an PUT request from angular. It works locally and when S3 bucket is public it works from CloudFront, but doesn't work from CloudFront when bucket isn't public. This is a different S3 bucket from the one CloudFront is using for S3 Static Website hosting.

If I make the bucket where I'm trying to upload image publicly available and use this bucket policy

```
{
  "Id": "BucketPolicy",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllAccess",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
         "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
         "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
      ],
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

It works perfectly from CloudFront, but as soon as I make it not public I get 403 forbidden.
To try and solve this I create a 2nd origin under CloudFront distribution for non s3 website bucket and copied the policy generated from image and added the policy to permissions for the S3 bucket I'm uploading image to, but I get 403 forbidden? Am I missing a step to making this work?

[image]

Bucket Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name>/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::<placeholder>:distribution/<placeholder>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I changed the generated policy that originally had `"Action": "s3:getObject"` to
`"Action": "s3:*"` before saving change in S3 permissions since I'm doing a PUT request from angular, but same issue.

Angular

```
   uploadfileAWSS3(s3SignedUrl, contenttype, file) {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file, 'updatedImage.png');
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'image/png'
        });
        const req = new HttpRequest('PUT', s3SignedUrl, file, {
            headers
        });
        return this.http.request(req);
    }
```

I also tried setting it up with legacy access identities where it automatically updates bucket policy. Then I updated `s3:getObject` to `s3:*` since I'm doing putObject for this test and it still gives me message forbidden. Why isn't this working?

I also noticed that the response in the browser says `There were headers present in the request which were not signedhost`

Since it might be a header issue. Here is the response with signed url minus security stuff showing the headers it returns
[image]

AND
here are the request and response headers when doing the PUT request into S3 bucket with image. Not sure if this useful, but trying to be thorough.

[image]
I appreciate any help!

Comment: are you getting 403 while uploading the object or reading the obj?

if you're making the bucket public (both read & write), then there is no meaning of using signed url right.

Comment: It happens when uploading the object. The bucket isn't only public and should only be accessible using OAI. I don't need to read the object, I'm using an S3 Lambda trigger after the upload to do something with the object. Users aren't reading the object themselves.

Comment: If the problem is with uploading - it has nothing to do with CloudFront. You are using signed urls. For them you need to specify all data that will be sent. As your error states there should also be header "host" set in signed URL. Otherwise, signatures don't match

Comment: I updated post to include headers that are used in getSignedURL() and PUT request. Host is there if you look at last image.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the answer, but I recommend focusing your efforts on bucket permissions, including the bucket policy. You should focus your efforts there because you said that when the bucket is public the code works, and this heavily implies that the issue is with your CloudFront distribution not being able to access the S3 bucket.

Here is some of a CloudFormation template I have which is working which allows GET:

```
- Action:
    - 's3:GetObject'
  Effect: Allow
  Resource: !Join
    - ''
    - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
      - !Ref YourS3Bucket
      - /*
  Principal:
    Service:
      - "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
  Condition:
    StringEquals:
      aws:SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:cloudfront::${AWS::AccountId}:distribution/${DistributionId}"
```

This looks identical to your own ACL, and I know my ACL is working.

I strongly suspect that the issue is that you need PUT permission because you said, "and performing an PUT request from angular". In that case, the permission list ought to be expanded from just including `s3:GetObject` to also including `s3:GetObjectVersion` `s3:PutObject` `s3:DeleteObject`.

You also may need to create a second set of permissions in the same ACL to target the bucket itself. Note the key changes - different permissions **AND a different RESOURCE** because List Resource is for all objects in bucket, so it is based on bucket name, not object path.

```
- Action:
    - 's3:ListBucket'
  Effect: Allow
  Resource: !Join
    - ''
    - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
      - !Ref YourS3Bucket
  Principal:
    Service:
      - "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
  Condition:
    StringEquals:
      aws:SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:cloudfront::${AWS::AccountId}:distribution/${DistributionId}"
```

Comment: The bucket policy generated by CloudFront initally set it to s3:GetObject, but I tweaked it to Action": "`s3:*". to account for PUT request. I updated bucket policy in post above to be more clear about current bucket permissions in S3. That should cover all S3 actions including ones you listed. I plan to be more specific with s3 actions after validating fix. You say to create another resource, but doesn't ```"arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket", "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"``` cover getObject and listObject already? Unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: I've never tried to use more than one Resource element within a single policy but it does say it's possible https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_resource.html#reference_policies_elements_resource_multiple-resources

If you're using 2 Resource elements `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket", "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*` with the Action 's3:*' then yes CloudFront should have permission to do a PUT.

Is your PUT URL in Angular bypassing CloudFront and going straight to the bucket? In other words, is `s3SignedUrl` a URL bypassing CloudFront? If so the policy won't work

Comment: The signed url is generated from the s3 static website that's behind the CloudFront distribution. If the bucket policy is public then I can do the PUT request. It only stops working when I try and point it to OAI and make bucket not public. The PUT request is coming from that same static website behind CloudFront distribution. Not sure if that answers your question though.

Comment: If the signed URL goes through CloudFront like `example.com/some/path?X-Amz-Signature=12b74b0788aa0361&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&otherstuff=blah` then it should work with the ACL because the PUT is granted to the `cloudfront.amazonaws.com` principal with the condition being that it's a particular CF distribution. However, if the URL is through an S3 domain like `https://presignedurldemo.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/` it wouldn't work because the principal would not be `cloudfront.amazonaws.com` and the condition would also not be true.

Comment: If the URL is something like `https://presignedurldemo.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/` then I've been wasting a bunch of time here - the issue is that you need a way to grant public access to GetObject so that people can view this object only when the object is a signed URL. I do not know how to do that. Sorry.

Comment: Part of the problem here is that presigned URLs seem to bypass some but not all of AWS's restrictions on GET-ing objects in S3 buckets, and I haven't spent the time to find out which ones are being bypassed and which ones are still enforced. I think that when you made the bucket public you turned off all restrictions; but knowing which combination of ACL / public access settings / etc which S3 uses to control access to S3 objects also affects access to S3 signed URLs is not something I know.

Comment: The presigned url is an s3 url ie https://bucket-images.s3.amazonaws.com. The goal is to kick off a S3 lambda trigger when PUT request happens and send the image somewhere else so people aren't going to be viewing the image directly from s3 bucket in this use case.